# Can i embed LINQ results into CDATA?

Tags: html, xml, vb.net, linq-to-xml, cdata

Can i merge the values returned from a LINQ query (in the next example c.day) with CDATA like...

```
Dim Result = <items>
             <%= From c In db.News Select _
              <item>
                <day><![CDATA[<font size="30" color="#7CBEBD"><%= c.day %></font>]]></day>
              </item> %>
            </items>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you can use CDATA section literals and embedded expressions inside them with VB.NET but you can certainly construct a CDATA section node with `new XCData()` as in the following example:

```
Dim words As String() = {"foo", "bar", "baz"}
Dim doc As XDocument =
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <root>
        <items>
            <%= From word In words
                Select <item>
                           <%= New XCData("<font size=""3"">" + word + "</font>") %>
                       </item>
            %>
        </items>
    </root>
```

That serializes as

```
<root>
  <items>
    <item><![CDATA[<font size="3">foo</font>]]></item>
    <item><![CDATA[<font size="3">bar</font>]]></item>
    <item><![CDATA[<font size="3">baz</font>]]></item>
  </items>
</root>
```